# Looking for a strategy to ensure name of child node stays unique in collection

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, strategy, relationships

<sup>Even though I'm programming in PHP, I'm open to reviewing language-agnostic suggestions, as they might point me to valuable directions.</sup>

<sup>**To remove any possible confusion I feel some comments appear to allude to: the** `Page`s **in this question do not refer to web pages, but to in-memory pages for an API akin to word processing and/or a spreadsheet.**</sup>

I have a `Page` class whose instances can be part of a `Pages` collection. These `Page` objects must be uniquely named if they're part of a `Pages` collection, as they must be uniquely identifiable by their name.

A `Page` object can never belong to multiple `Pages` collections at the same time: they will either be moved, or be copied (cloned).

Consumers will also be able to alter the name of individual `Page` objects, for instance with<sup>1</sup>:

```php
$page = new Page( 'Optional name' );
// or ($pages is a Pages collection instance)
$page = $pages->getByName( 'Page 1' );

// and then
$page->setName( 'My Page' );
```

If a `Page` is added to a `Pages` collection, the collection will ensure the `Page` is renamed, if its name conflicts with another `Page` in the collection, like so:

```php
class Pages
{
  private $objectIndex;
  private $nameIndex;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->objectIndex = new SplObjectStorage;
    $this->nameIndex = [];
  }

  public function add( Page $page ) {
    if( !$this->objectIndex->contains( $page ) ) {
      $name = $page->getName();
      if( isset( $this->nameIndex[ $name ] ) ) {
        // make name unique to this collection
        $name = $this->someLogicToMakeNameUnique( $name );
        // alter name
        $page->setName( $name );
      }
      $this->nameIndex[ $name ] = $page;
      $this->objectIndex->attach( $page, $name );
    }
  }

  public function getByName( $name ) {
    if( isset( $this->nameIndex[ $name ] ) ) {
      $this->nameIndex[ $name ];
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to come up with a strategy to make sure that, if a `Page` is part of a collection and its name is altered, the name automatically gets adjusted to a unique name (i.e. if `"Page 1"` already exists, rename it to `"Page 2"`) and that the `Pages::$nameIndex` keys get properly updated as well (as this allows for faster retrieval of a `Page` by name than looping through it's contained `Page`s until a name matches).

Strategies I've come up with so far are:

1. Pass `Pages` collection to `Page::setParent( Pages $container )` and call some verification/sanitation mechanism on `$this->container` in `Page::setName( $name )`, before altering.
2. Emit a `rename` event from `Page::setName( $name )` and have `Pages` do something like `$event->preventDefault()` if the name conflicts and then have `Pages` alter the name to something unique instead.

Option 1 seems the easiest/laziest/least process intensive, but puts the responsibility of verifying uniqueness in an object where it does not belong.

Option 2 appeals the most to me so far, but it has a downside as well: It will emit multiple `rename` events, if the `Pages` collection needs to alter the name itself again.

<sup>NB: Even though both the `Page::setParent( Pages $container )` (as a `Page` can only ever be owned by one collection) and event dispatching capabilities (primarily meant for consumer purposes) are already implemented, neither are utilized for my unique naming conundrum yet.</sup>

---

Do you have any other suggestions that satisfy the constraints that `Pages` should be responsible for verifying uniqueness and that there's not to much back-and-forth communication necessary?

---

<sup>1) As a reference: my objective is akin to Excel VBA's `Workbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Name = "Sheet"` type of behavior, which I believe behaves similar to what I am after.</sup>

Comment: Can a `Page` object belong to more than one `Pages` collection? Or is there always a unique "parent container" of a page?

Comment: @DocBrown  Good question! I forgot to mention that a `Page` can never belong to multiple `Pages` collections at once. I'll update my question with this information.

Comment: I am too lazy to write an actual answer, but created a [PHP snippet for you to look at](https://pastebin.com/Ms4RXVJS). The example deals with the circular reference while keeping the responsibility of uniqueness in the place where it belongs, in the `Pages` object.

Comment: Does the name of a page even make sense outside of a pages collection? Shouldn't the name be a property of the association between a pages collection and a page instead of a property of the page? Similar to how the index of an object in an array is a property of the "being in an array" and not a property of the object?

Comment: @DavidPacker Hahaha, holy sh...! Too lazy to write an answer, but gives a full-fletched solution instead. Hahaha, I like your style, man. And I really feel bad for saying this, as I see what you are doing and I'm sure it works as expected, but unfortunately it uses completely different paradigms than what I am envisioning: your solution revolves around the repository pattern (and the strategy pattern, which may actually be useful), but I feel this would be too cumbersome for my intended API-consumers, unless I can somehow encapsulate this behind my API. ...

Comment: ...I'll have to investigate your proposal some more to see which parts I could actually use. Thanks a lot in any case! Really appreciate your effort.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, sorry for any possible confusion: the `Page` objects refer to objects similar to Office application pages, like a powerpoint page, spreadsheet sheet, word processing page, etc. The pages need to be retrievable by their names and their names need to be able to be altered. Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uniqueness of those names is a property which is clearly defined **only** in context of a `Pages` collection. That is most easiest understood when you think of a `Page` object changing its "parent" container, or a `Page` object with no parent container at all.

Thus *verifying uniqueness* is clearly a responsibility of the `Pages` class, not of a `Page`. As a consequence, when the verification/sanitation mechanism is implemented in `Pages`, it is exactly where it belongs to. Calling this mechanism from `Page::setName` does not change the responsibility, so your "Option 1" is perfectly ok.

As a side note: the most simple "verification/sanitation mechanism" I can think of is to simply forbid any name change of a `Page` once it has been assigned to a `Pages` collection. This simple strategy might be totally sufficient for several use cases. If a page has to be renamed, it needs to be taken out of the collection first, then renamed, and then added again by using the `add` method in your example.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I totally agree with your first paragraph and the first sentence of your second paragraph, about it being `Pages` responsibility. But that's exactly why I'm not too fond of my first option: I feel that a `Page` should not *at all* be concerned with name uniqueness and it should not be a `Page`'s responsibility to verify with its parent whether a name is allowed. And addressing your last paragraph: I'd rather retain that functionality for consumer-friendliness, especially since they would otherwise also have to remember its position (as the collection is ordered as well).

Comment: @DecentDabbler: ok, it seems I misunderstood your question. It seems when you wrote *"puts the responsibility of verifying uniqueness in an object where it does not belong"* you did not mean the `Pages` object, but the `Page` object. But to my understanding, the responsibility *is* in the `Pages` object in this solution, the fact the validation is *called* from within the `Page` object does not change this.

Comment: @DecentDabbler: see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that confusing bit; I was talking about `Page` indeed. And thanks again: I may actually end up using this after all if no other viable solutions come up or if other solutions end up being too cumbersome. At a minimum I'm going to ponder on this option some more.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention (I've updated my question to reflect this as well), is that this solution still does not yet make `Pages` automatically update its named index (used for fast retrieval of `Page`s by their name), but I guess I could make a more elaborate method on `Pages` like `Pages::renamePage( Page $page, $newName )`, in stead of just a simple verification method. So, in `Page::rename( $name )` (simplified): `if( $this->hasParent() ) { $this->parent->renamePage( $this, $name ); } else { $this->name = $name; }`.

Comment: @DecentDabbler: either this, or you use the ["null object pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) where you have a special null object of type `Pages` which is used as a default parent for each page as long as there is no "real" parent container. For this object, the `renamePage` method does nothing than simply. assigning the new name. Not sure if this is overengineered for your case. If the "renamePage" turns out to be the only use case for the "null object", I would probably not go this route. If, however, you get a lot of `if( $this->hasParent()`, then it makes sense.

Comment: Oooh, I like that suggestion... yes! I might end up using that indeed. I'll have to ponder on what the consequences for the ultimate API consumers will be (who will also be able to call `hasParent()`, `getParent()`, etc.), but I think I'll be able to find a solution to that. Thanks!